# The value in array is not displaying in C

Tags: arrays, c, printf

**This is my code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() {
  int opt, element;
  char name[10][10] = {"Hytrogen","oxygen","Mercury"};
  printf("WELCOME TO PERIODIC TABLE IMPLEMENTATION USING C LANGUAGE \n");
  printf("Please enter the atomic number of any element to view its details\n");
  scanf("%d", &opt);
  printf("\nThe entered option is %d", opt);
  element = opt+1;
  printf("\nAtomic numbere is : %d", element);
  printf("\nName of the element is : ");
  printf(name[element]);  
}
```

**The output I get**

```
WELCOME TO PERIODIC TABLE IMPLEMENTATION USING C LANGUAGE
Please enter the atomic number of any element to view its details
2
The entered option is 2
Atomic numbere is : 3
Name of the element is :
```

Why the element name is not printing at the last line `Name of the element is :` ??

I tried on an online compiller

Comment: Please format your code properly.  Also, array indexes start from 0.

Comment: Cause you have only 3 elements in elements name array. Only 0 & 1 will return valid response.

Comment: `printf(name[opt]);`

Comment: Instead of `element = opt+1;`, you should do `element = opt - 1;`.

Comment: Using `scanf()` on user input without checking return value -> `opt` may be used uninitialized.

Answer (score 0):

@dbush already answered why it is not working (The array index starts from 0). Here is one way to do it properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
  int atomic_num;
  // TODO(Thomaskutty A): Increase the array size to 118 and add all the elements
  char element_names[10][10] = {"Hydrogen", "Helium", "Lithium", "Beryllium"};
  printf("WELCOME TO PERIODIC TABLE IMPLEMENTATION USING C LANGUAGE\n");
  printf("Please enter the atomic number of any element to view its details: ");
  scanf("%d", &atomic_num);
  // TODO(Thomaskutty A): Validate user input
  printf("The entered number is %d\n", atomic_num);
  printf("Name of the element is: %s\n", element_names[atomic_num - 1]);
}
```

You should add checks to validate user input. NTUI (Never Trust User Input).

As @dbush said, give a little cleanup (formatting, removal of unnecessary characters, use of good variable names, and fixing grammar errors/typos...) to your code before posting it to SO. People who do this for a living hate it when they see badly written code.

Happy coding, and keep on learning... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Index of an array starts from `0`.

Content of `name` array at index `0`, `1` and `2` -

```
              +-------------------+
    name[0] ->|H|y|d|r|o|g|e|n|0|0|
              +-------------------+

              +-------------------+
    name[1] ->|o|x|y|g|e|n|0|0|0|0|
              +-------------------+

              +-------------------+
    name[2] ->|M|e|r|c|u|r|y|0|0|0|
              +-------------------+
```

Instead of adding `1` to user input, you should subtract `1` from user input because you are taking atomic number of element as input from user:

```
element = opt - 1;
          ^^^^^^^
```

If user give input at `1`, your program should display `Hydrogen` which exists at index `0` of `name` array, for input `2`, you program should display `oxygen` which exists at index `1` of `name` array and so on.

Also, using `void` as return type of `main()` function is not as per standards. The return type of `main()` function should be `int`.